# react-hook-form Controller `as` property missing from latest version?

Tags: controller, typeerror, react-hook-form

I am using `"react-hook-form": "^7.34.2",` and bump into the following error:

```
Type error: Type '{ as: FC<TextFieldProps>; control: Control<AddressFormValues, any>; name: `${string}.address`; label: string; error: boolean; helperText: string; rules: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<AddressFormValues, `${string}.address`>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: UseFormStateReturn<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'.
  Property 'as' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<AddressFormValues, `${string}.address`>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: UseFormStateReturn<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'.

  31 |     <Stack spacing={2.5}>
  32 |       <Controller
> 33 |         as={TextField}
     |         ^
  34 |         control={control}
  35 |         name={`${prefix}.address`}
  36 |         label={`${labelPrefix}`}
```